# Sencha nested list with html button

Tags: sencha-touch

I am quite new to Sencha. My requirement is to add a html button to the nested list each item that will post the selected item to web API.

```
{
              xtype: 'nestedlist',
              title: 'Jobs',
              iconCls: 'star',

              getItemTextTpl: function (node) {
                  return '<div style="float:left">{text}</div><div style="float:right"> 
                      '<input type="button" title="xyz" value="pqr"  id="someID"/></div>';


              },


              store: {
                  type: 'tree',

                  fields: [
                      'text', 'id', 'name', 'title',
                      { name: 'leaf', defaultValue: true }
                  ],

                  root: {
                      leaf: false
                  },

                  proxy: {
                      type: 'rest',
                      url: 'http://localhost/AD/api/jobs/',
                      reader: {
                          type: 'json',
                          //  rootProperty: 'root'
                      }
                  }
              },

              detailCard: {
                  xtype: 'panel',
                  scrollable: true,
                  styleHtmlContent: true
              },

              listeners: {
                  itemtap: function (nestedList, list, index, element, post) {
                      debugger;
                      this.getDetailCard().setHtml('<pre><h4>Log</h4>' + post.get('AuditLog') + '</pre>');
                  },                    

              }
```

I want to attach event listener to the button 'SomeID' so that the item should be posted to the web api for further processing and then refresh the nested list after the processing is done.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
    listeners: {
                      itemtap: function (nestedList, list, index, element, post,e) {
                         if (e.getTarget(someID)){
                                // do something here in button tap
                         }
                          else{
                          this.getDetailCard().setHtml('<pre><h4>Log</h4>' + post.get('AuditLog') + '</pre>');
}

},
```

Comment: How to stop navigating to details card if the SomeID is clicked? I tried SuspendEvents(false) and return false but no joy. I want if SomeID button clicked it should stay on the nested list and post to web api and update the record and refresh the list. On normal tap on the list switch to the details cards. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Dibish, How to stop the item tap event if the button is clicked and stay on the same nested list page? Please refer my previous comment for details. Thanks